# Using Forfiles in order to delete logs older than 1 day, but the command fails because one of the logs is being used

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I went through the `forfiles /?` but couldn't find a way to skip these files.
My command looks like this:

```
forfiles /P e:logfiles\ /S /M *.log /D -1 /C "cmd /c del /f @fname.log"
```

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!